# Keyboard to show notification not called iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, keyboard, ios12

In my app, I wanted a notification for `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` in order to update the y position of my text field. It was working prior to iOS 12; now, it is not called in one of my view controllers (it works for other ones).

Here is my code to do this:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("keyboard will show 2")
    guard let frameValue: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
        return
    }
    let keyboardFrame = frameValue.cgRectValue
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationTime) {
        self.addViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        print("Bottom contraint height = \(self.addViewBottomConstraint.constant)")
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationTime) {
        self.addViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Here, "keyboard will show 2" is not printed, but it is printed for other view controllers with the same notifications. Is there anything new in iOS 12 that caused this? Otherwise, is there a particular reason why it is not being called?

Comment: Do you remove the observation anywhere such as when view disappears ??

Comment: I do so in deinit

Comment: Check it on iOS 11 once on the simulator or any device that is not updated to iOS 12 yet.

Comment: Log on this view controller’s `deinit`. I bet it is going out of existence prematurely.

Comment: It turns out that it does not work on iOS 11 either. Additionally, I commented out the deinit but it still doesn't work

Comment: As far as I know, the function for keyboardWillShow is not called until a ui component is on screen and becomeFirstResponder is called. Maybe you could share that part of your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to simulator setup, see menu "Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Keyboard Hardware". If this option is ON, you will get UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, but never UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.